# Collection is not loaded correctly in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have loaded my Java entities with Eclipse Link into my project. It's a simple relation for `User` - `Rol` model, but I don't know why it just does not load the `Rol` list for the user.

Here is my generated code. It is killing me since the log shows the correct query and even shows that it loads the rol, but never appears on the user class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String username;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Rol
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "usuario_has_rol",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "usuario_username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "rol_id_rol")})
    private List<Rol> rols;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The Rol class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rol")
@NamedQuery(name = "Rol.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Rol r")
public class Rol implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_rol")
    private int idRol;

    @Column(name = "rol_name")
    private String rolName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RolHasMenu
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rol")
    private List<RolHasMenu> rolHasMenus;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Usuario
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rols")
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The log shows the following (where I can see that the rol is correctly loaded)

```
21:59:17,112 TRACE EntityReferenceInitializerImpl:245 - hydrating entity state
21:59:17,112 TRACE EntityReferenceInitializerImpl:297 - Initializing object from ResultSet: [org.inkasoft.edustat.model.Rol#2]
21:59:17,113 TRACE AbstractEntityPersister:2901 - Hydrating entity: [org.inkasoft.edustat.model.Rol#2]
21:59:17,113 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([rol_name2_19_4_] : [VARCHAR]) - [ROL_USER]
21:59:17,113 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([usuario_1_24_3_] : [VARCHAR]) - [jaxkodex]
21:59:17,113 DEBUG CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl:77 - Found row of collection: [org.inkasoft.edustat.model.Usuario.rols#jaxkodex]
21:59:17,113 TRACE LoadContexts:171 - Constructing collection load context for result set [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@3954b0d3]
21:59:17,114 TRACE CollectionLoadContext:112 - Starting attempt to find loading collection [[org.inkasoft.edustat.model.Usuario.rols#jaxkodex]]
21:59:17,114 TRACE CollectionLoadContext:138 - Instantiating new collection [key=jaxkodex, rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@3954b0d3]
21:59:17,114 TRACE BasicExtractor:78 - extracted value ([rol_id_r2_25_3_] : [INTEGER]) - [2]
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Also you need to declare the type of list for rols for example like this `private List<Rol> rols = new ArrayList<Rol>();` using `ArrayList`

Comment: Please add getters/setters code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Chaitanya pointed, you need to specify the type of underlying list implementation class,

```
private List<Rol> rols = new ArrayList<Rol>();
```

Alternatively, in getter method

```
public List<Rol> getRols() {
    if(rols == null) {
        rols = new ArrayList<Rol>();
    }
    return rols;
}
```